# How to add more tags to whitelist list of loofah in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Ruby on Rails Version 7.0.4
Ruby Version: 3.1.3

I want to sanitize the content with Rails Loofah gem, it works perfectly fine.
But based on the project needs certain tag and attributes needs to be included while scrubbing the content.

Like  tag,  tag

How can we add additional tags along with the default list that loofah provide.
Using

```
Loofah.fragment("<style>{font-family:'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif;}</style>  <script>alert(h1)</script> <a href='https://google.com'>something</a> <div>Later</div>").scrub!(:prune).scrub!(:nofollow).to_s
```

Style Tag is what i need to add in white list, along with other default tags